# Problem with shadows in Xamarin.Forms with Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, frame, shadow

[image: Screenshot]

How can I eliminate the shadow inherited from the elements under the `<Frame>`?
In the image you can see that in the first block ("With shadow") all the elements that have a background color inherit the shadow of the red Frame (which has the property HasShadow = "True"), while in the second block it does not inherit it because the HasShadow property is False. This incorrect behavior occurs only in Android, while it works properly in iOS.
How can I not inherit the shadow?

Here is the XML:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Image Source="{ext:ImageResource AppBasic.Images.Icons.close.png}"/>
    <ffimage:CachedImage Source="{ext:ImageResource AppBasic.Images.Layout.user.png}" />
    <StackLayout Spacing="10">
        <!-- with shadow -->
        <Label Text="With shadow" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="S-Bold" />
        <Frame HasShadow="True" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="56" HeightRequest="56" CornerRadius="28" BackgroundColor="Red" />
        <f9p:Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Fit="Lines" Lines="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green">GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT</f9p:Label>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Orange" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"></StackLayout>
        <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent">Text</Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Spacing="10">
        <!-- without shadow -->
        <Label Text="Without shadow" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="S-Bold" />
        <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="56" HeightRequest="56" CornerRadius="28" BackgroundColor="Red" />
        <f9p:Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Fit="Lines" Lines="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green">GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT GIFT</f9p:Label>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Orange" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"></StackLayout>
        <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent">Text</Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug... You can wrap the `Frame` on a `Grid` to fix this behavior.

```
...
<Grid>
    <Frame HasShadow="True" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="56" HeightRequest="56" CornerRadius="28" BackgroundColor="Red" />
</Grid>
...
```

Comment: Yes of course, or I could remove the background color from the objects (because that's the problem / bug). But it doesn't seem like the optimal solution to wrap in a grid

Answer (score 0):

You could implement shadow on each element by using Effect .

#### in Forms

```
public class ShadowEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public float DistanceX { get; set; }

    public float DistanceY { get; set; }

    public ShadowEffect () : base ("MyCompany.LabelShadowEffect")
    {           
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(LabelShadowEffect), "LabelShadowEffect")]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class LabelShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                var effect = (ShadowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ShadowEffect);
                if (effect != null)
                {
                    Control.Layer.ShadowRadius = effect.Radius;
                    Control.Layer.ShadowColor = effect.Color.ToCGColor();
                    Control.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(effect.DistanceX, effect.DistanceY);
                    Control.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
[assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(LabelShadowEffect), "LabelShadowEffect")]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class LabelShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached ()
        {
            try {
                var control = Control as Android.Widget.TextView;
                var effect = (ShadowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault (e => e is ShadowEffect);
                if (effect != null) {
                    float radius = effect.Radius;
                    float distanceX = effect.DistanceX;
                    float distanceY = effect.DistanceY;
                    Android.Graphics.Color color = effect.Color.ToAndroid ();
                    control.SetShadowLayer (radius, distanceX, distanceY, color);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And in Xmal

```
<Label Text="Label Shadow Effect" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.Effects>
        <local:ShadowEffect Radius="5" DistanceX="5" DistanceY="5">
            <local:ShadowEffect.Color>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                      <On Platform="iOS" Value="Black" />
                      <On Platform="Android" Value="Red" />                           
                </OnPlatform>
            </local:ShadowEffect.Color>
        </local:ShadowEffect>
    </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

You can add the effect on any elements like Image or Entry .

Comment: Hi, I don't want the shadow in every single element. The problem / bug is that if I put a <Frame> that has the shadow and then I put a <StackLayout> or a <Label> etc ... with a background color, these elements have inexplicably the shadow

Comment: It seems a design issue with frame .